# Игровой автомат с помощью List View

Tags: android, c#, listview, прокрутка, xamarin

Хочу кодом "прокручивать" List View. Не совсем понятно как работает скролл в ListView, как получить его расположение. Пытаюсь изменить позицию с помощью метода `ScrollTo` , но ничего не происходит в любой позиции

Представляют это примерно так: С помощью метода установки прокрутки каждую сотую секунду сдвигаю позицию скролла на N вниз. Если достигли края, то устанавливаем позицию скролла противоположного края и продолжаем сдвигать.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Views;

namespace TestChart
{
    [Activity(Label = "Slot Machine", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2","Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button buttonRoll = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonRoll);
            ListView listViewSlotMachine = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewSlotMachine);

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.my_list_item, values);

            // присваиваем адаптер списку
            listViewSlotMachine.Adapter = adapter;

            buttonRoll.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                listViewSlotMachine.ScrollTo(0, 0); // ничего не происходит
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://java-help.ru/scroll-to-a-selected-position-in-listview/

Comment: @pavlofff Можно ли это сделать без анимации?

Comment: @pavlofff такой вариант не подходит, чтобы переместить ползунок мгновенно на другую границу и продолжить скроллить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// Scroll sample
/// </summary>
private async void TestScroll()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    ListView.SetSelection(30); //без анимации
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    ListView.SmoothScrollToPosition(50); //с анимацией
}
```